# InertiaJs - Loader Percentage / Progress Percentage Not Working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I am working on Laravel + InertiaJs with Vue3 , I just created a new project and following a simple Inertia Form submit example here it is , .

```
<script setup>
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const form = useForm({
  name: null,
  avatar: null,
})

function submit() {
  form.post('/users')
}
</script>

<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <input type="text" v-model="form.name" />
    <input type="file" @input="form.avatar = $event.target.files[0]" />
    progress v-if="form.progress" :value="form.progress.percentage" max="100">
      {{ form.progress.percentage }}%
    </progress>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Here this Code just shows loader , but loader completes to 100 just once . I does not work like the main loader that shows at the top of the page.

```
    <progress v-if="form.progress" :value="form.progress.percentage" max="100">
      {{ form.progress.percentage }}%
    </progress>
```

I tried this

```
createInertiaApp({
  progress: {
    // The delay after which the progress bar will appear, in milliseconds...
    delay: 250,

    // The color of the progress bar...
    color: '#29d',

    // Whether to include the default NProgress styles...
    includeCSS: true,

    // Whether the NProgress spinner will be shown...
    showSpinner: false,
  },
  // ...
})
```